# Adding table space in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a video slider and I use bootstrap for this. Now I've inserted a table within the slider(carousel). It works perfectly but I'm changing the layout. The picture below is the layout I want. I've managed to put the background. The problem is I can't insert a space between the columns of the description. How can I insert space in each of the column?

[image]

```
  .rowTwo{
  background-color: #491f43;
  }
  .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}
  h1{
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px;
  }
  .txt_txt{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  }
```

body

```
  <div class="item active">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:265px; height: 185px;"></iframe></td>
                    <td align="center"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:265px; height: 185px;"></iframe></td>
                    <td align="center"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:265px; height: 185px;"></iframe></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="rowTwo">
                        <h1>Video Title<h1>
                        <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rowTwo">
                        <h1>Video Title<h1>
                        <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rowTwo">
                        <h1>Video Title<h1>
                        <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                    </td>                       
            </table>  
  </div>
```

[preview site](https://site-practice-chum.c9.io/videoslider_bootstrap.html)

Comment: What type of space you exacly want? Maybe you are talking about `padding` or `margin`.

Comment: I've added it before but it didn't work.  both margin ang padding

Comment: You could try using bootstrap's grid system instead of a table. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Try this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AlUGUx48tz1GCZVDZvdk you'll need to expand the preview window completely to see it correctly, otherwise it'll show as it would be seen on a small screen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work. but you can have something like this

```
<div class="item active">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" style="padding:0px">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:100%; height: 185px;"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" >
                      <h1>Video Title<h1>
                       <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" style="padding:0px">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:100%; height: 185px;"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" >
                      <h1>Video Title<h1>
                       <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" style="padding:0px">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:100%; height: 185px;"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" >
                      <h1>Video Title<h1>
                       <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                </div>
            </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This puts space between each of the table data cells, coming close to what you are trying to achieve, without all the extra styling.

```css
table {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-spacing: 30px !important;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="item active">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:265px; height: 185px;"></iframe>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:265px; height: 185px;"></iframe>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed//9cVusLdlC8U&quot;/&gt;?html5=1&amp;wmode=transparent" style="border: 10px solid #2C2B2B; width:265px; height: 185px;"></iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rowTwo">
      <h1>Video Title<h1>
                        <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rowTwo">
                        <h1>Video Title<h1>
                        <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rowTwo">
                        <h1>Video Title<h1>
                        <span class="txt_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, nunc sit amet condimentum aliquam, elit nulla tincidunt urna, quis dapibus augue ligula sed neque. Proin sit amet turpis at dui ultricies imperdiet. Morbi egestas augue at risus congue egestas. Morbi a egestas ante. Donec eget magna dui.</span>
                    </td>                       
            </table>  
  </div>
```